# Variable not expanding when using regex operator (=~)

Tags: regex, bash, shell, zsh

I'm trying to filter out the lines of a variable matching the regex stored in `$pat` and the following condition:

`[[ $line =~ $pat ]]`

However, when running the debugger with `set -x` to show the execution after expansions, the variable `$line` and `$pat` are not expanding. In fact I have tried the regex operation with any variable and the result is the same: no expansion.

I've tried running the code with BASH instead of ZSH. I've tried switching the order of the `if` conditions.
I've tried `"$line"` and `${line}`. The variables are not expanding.

**My code:**

```
set -x
pat='\s+main\('
while read line
do
    if [[ $line != *"/*"* ]] && [[ $line = *[^[:space:]]* ]] && [[ $line =~ $pat ]]
    then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done <<< $prot_list
```

**The commands executed with expansions from debugger:**

```
+./prototypical.sh:39> [[ 'int prot_test2(char c);' != */\** ]]
+./prototypical.sh:39> [[ 'int prot_test2(char c);' = *[^[:space:]]* ]]
+./prototypical.sh:39> [[ $line -regex-match $pat ]]
```

As shown above, the first 2 conditions of the `if` expand the variables, but not the 3rd condition.

Comment: That's intentional. `$` is a regular expression pattern, it can't also be the variable prefix.

Comment: `$line` should be expanded, though.

Comment: `\s` is not a special escape sequence in bash or zsh-default extended regular expressions, btw.

Comment: Works for me in bash, zsh, and ksh if I use `[[:space:]]` instead of `\s` (i.e. `pat='[[:space:]]+main\('`). zsh's trace output matches what you have, but it works properly. bash and ksh show the variables expanded.

Comment: @Barmar : both zsh and bash expand `$pat` here.`line="  main("; pat=' +main[(]'; [[ $line =~ $pat ]] && echo x` outputs _x_.